# User is unable to login with Facebook after app update on Android with Parse SDK

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I am using Parse SDK on my Android device. In our app, user can login with Facebook.

Everything works fine if the user install the app first time and tries to login with Facebook. However, if the user has already installed and logged in app and then tries to update to a new version, app shows a login screen. And when user tries to login with Facebook again, it fails and no error is shown. In MainActivity (launching activity), this is the code:

```
if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
     ParseLoginConfig config = new ParseLoginConfig();
     config.setFacebookLoginEnabled(true);
     intent.putExtras(config.toBundle());
     startActivityForResult(intent, LOGIN_REQUEST);
}
```

LoginActivity derives from ParseLoginActivity.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: now you must user facebook graph api for login with facebook

Comment: Vishal, are you suggesting that we cannot use inbuilt facebook login functionality that comes with Parse Android SDK?

Comment: no i don't suggest this but facebook have its own sdk for use their features so why are you not using that?

Comment: Because we manage user identity via Parse and Parse nicely merge Facebook identity with internal user identity

Comment: On "update" to new version - there must be something unforseen with 'data' and or 'cache' being cleared. That is where the client-side , cookie-like , identity for the app resides. On normal updated APK , the client-side identity would persist and client-account info will continue to be equal to server-side info indicating the same account.   see ParseUser class property for install ID or something like that.